# Ask about IP address exhaustion

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I am using openVPN with azure vpn P2S.
I would like to ask about IP address exhaustion.
The configuration of azure vpn is set up as follows.
I would like to use about 5000 for ip address usage.
In that case, what should the "address pool" and other settings of the "azure vnet gateway" be?

```
■ azure vnet subnet
- FrontEnd
- 10.1.0.0/24

GatewaySubnet
- 10.1.255.0/27

address space
- 10.0.0.0/16
- 10.1.0.0/16

■ azure vnet gateway
- address pool
- 172.16.201.0/24

tunnel type
- openVPN
```

Answer (score 0):

CIDR /24 will give you only 251 IPS (256, but 5 are reserved for Azure). You should use /19 at least, but it's more common a /16